# Disable Transfer Encoding Chunked in glassfish/soap java webservices

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, glassfish

I have developed a soap web services from wsdl in Netbeans and deployed to glassfish server.

The client call an endpoint and the webservices respond but in the reponse header i have:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I'd like ti disable this transfer encoding and set Content-Length: where i must disable this type of transfer? In glassfish? How?

Answer (score 2):

In the domain.xml in Glassfish, in this tag:

```
 <protocol security-enabled="true" name="http-listener-2">
            <http  chunking-enabled="false"  default-virtual-server="server" max-connections="250">
              <file-cache></file-cache>
            </http>
            <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname="s1as"></ssl>
```

Set chunking-enabled="false"

This also removes some random characters I was getting spread out in the response.